# Rsync returns no such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I use the following command to try to get a file to my ubuntu 14.04 server from another server (centos I think) using rsync

```
rsync -r -e -ssh root@<ip>:/home/<user>/public_html/image.jpg /var/www/html/image.jpg
```

However I get the following error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec -ssh: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [Receiver=3.1.0]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

I can login through SSH without any issues and change folders to the directory.

I tried recursively put the home folder to 777 but this didn't work (I know I shouldn't do this but the server gets dropped in 2 days.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `-ssh`. After the `-e` option, there should come argument. Running

```
rsync -r -e ssh root@<ip>:/home/<user>/public_html/image.jpg /var/www/html/image.jpg
```

should do the job, but it is just equivalent to

```
rsync -r root@<ip>:/home/<user>/public_html/image.jpg /var/www/html/image.jpg
```

not sure what was your intention.